# Autocorrelation function of Arima(1,1,0)

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation

I have ARIMA(1,1,0) model:

```
(1-ΦB)(1-B)X_t = ε_t
```

Where ε_t ~ WN(0,σ^2), |Φ|<1, DX_0 < ∞.

How do I calculate the autocorrelation function?

Comment: Consider the definition of [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation).

Comment: Is $\operatorname{WN}(0, \sigma^2)$ a [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process)?

Comment: @Galen ε_t ~ WN(0,σ^2) is a White Noise with E(ε_t)=0, D^2(ε_t)=σ^2 and cov(ε_t, ε_s)=0 when t is not equal s.